# XAML code in powershell doesn't run?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xaml, powershell-4.0

So I've been experimenting on integrating multithreaded XAML GUI to some powershell scripts I've written to make them better appealing(I have very little experience with C#).

Everything works completely fine on my home computer, yet when I have transferred the code to my enterprise computers Literally nothing happens. No exceptions, no errors, just nothing.

I thought it's a .net and powershell version gaps yet I've checked and both are completely the same. Tried running  powershell.exe -sta, ,adding presentationfranework types, no help.

I used the example code from this link:
https://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/

After some debugging the only thing I've found is the following:

1)When I call the error method from the variable that is used to create a synchronized hashtable $synchash.Error, it says "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."(can't read everything because it stops halfway through)

2) when I run a variable that is supposed to create an xaml reader object $reader it says:
"A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.xml.xmlNodeReader"

I hope to know what exactly happens inside powershell when you use wpf and xaml code in that manner and maybe know what has caused this mysterious issue...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code you are using?

One of the issues I had was running it within ISE works fine but as soon as you try and run it from a Ps windows nothing happens.

Try adding this to the top of the script:
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, System.Windows.Forms

Rob